# Pandas ExcelWriter creates corrupt file even in try except statement

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel file with multiple sheets, one of which contains multiple data tables. I wrote a function to update the data tables in this file while keeping the rest of the sheets in tact. When saving you can overwrite the existing file or save it as a new file.

Here is the relevant code:

```py
try:
    wb=op.load_workbook(master_file)
    writer=pd.ExcelWriter(save_name, engine='openpyxl')
    writer.book=wb
    writer.sheets=dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in wb.worksheets)
    table1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="New Sheet")
            
    #Format and print more data tables....
            
    wb.remove(wb["Data Sheet"])
    wb["New Sheet"].title="Data Sheet"
    
except Exception:
    return
        
writer.close()
```

My code works fine when there are no errors however, if something goes wrong and it does throw an error then it spits out a corrupted excel file that can't be open and is 0kb.

I want to prevent this because if you try to overwrite an existing file and it happens to throw an error all of the information in the file would be lost. This would be a huge issue.

However even when in a try block that catches all exceptions, ExcelWriter still creates a corrupted excel file with the save name.

Comment: `try...except` gives *your code* to do something about the error. You seem to imagine it will fix the issue on its own. Start by taking the `try...except` out. Then, when your program fails, you will at least get a traceback pointing to the line that failed and the reason why. All you have done so far is make the *error message* go away. That does make your error go away.

Comment: There is no specific error. In the event of *any* error I need to make sure the data doesn't get overwritten with a corrupted file. This is part of an app that other people will be using. The code in the try block should only be getting executed if there are no errors, if there are it should exit out of the function instead with return. But pd.ExcelWriter is being created even if there is an error

Comment: Your code opens `writer` with `save_name` before ever it tries writing data to the file. That overwrites any existing file *before your code even starts to do something that could cause an error*. No amount of exception handing will recover a file that your code has already overwritten. Have your code write to a temporary file, do a `try...except` to exit in event of a problem, and after that, when you know the temporary file has been successfully written out, rename it to the name you actually want. And it would also be a good idea to report what went wrong.